# How to decode this little endian(int32) message?

Tags: python, arrays, string, hex

I have a task to do. I get lot of data and my job is to decode it. Every piece I get is written in readable string of hex numbers. For example: "8a fd ff ff"

I tried with `struct.unpack('<l', "8a fd ff ff")` and I also tried a lot of way to decode and it would be too long to list. Only thing I know that this should give me -630 as a result.
I don't know how the data was transformed to this form.

```
data = "8a fd ff ff"
aa = np.array(list(data))
print(aa)
struct.unpack('<l', aa)
```

> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

so the result should be -630. I tested it with an online hex decoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A find the first answer good, but a more intuitive, and easier to remember is following. Given that all of your data is given as a space separated string of hex numbers you can use :

```
data = "8a fd ff ff"
bytes_data = bytes.fromhex( data.strip() ) 
struct.unpack("<l", bytes_data)
```

In this example we first load the data, remove all the whitespaces, convert to binary hex representation and read it out. Output is as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

## Step-wise conversion from hex string to byte string

`unpack()` expects a byte string as the second argument (which must match the format as specified by the first argument). However, what we have now in `data` is `'8a fd ff ff'`, which is a hex string. So we need to convert the hex string into byte string by taking the steps below:

1. Split the data:

```py
data_split = data.split()
# ['8a', 'fd', 'ff', 'ff']
```

2. Now, the split data are still hex strings, so we need to read them as hex using `int()`, passing in `16` as the second argument because hexadecimal is base 16:

```py
data_converted = [int(hex_string, 16) for hex_string in data_split]
# [138, 253, 255, 255]
```

3. We can now convert the data to bytes:

```py
byte_array = [chr(int_) for int_ in data_converted]
# ['\x8a', '\xfd', '\xff', '\xff']
```

4. We then join the array into a single string:

```py
byte_string = ''.join(byte_array)
# '\x8a\xfd\xff\xff'
```

5. Finally, we can use `unpack()`, with the `l` format character for `long` (i.e., 4 bytes):

```py
unpack('<l', byte_string)
# (-630,)
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct.unpack` doesn't expect a string but a byte string: a sequence of bytes in the binary form.

```
 >>> data = "8a fd ff ff"
 >>> bytestr = "".join(chr(int(h, 16)) for h in data.split())
 >>> struct.unpack("<l", bytestr )
 (-630,)
```

Your array has a list of the string representations characters instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = "8a fd ff ff"
>>> aa = np.array(list(data))>>> aa
array(['8', 'a', ' ', 'f', 'd', ' ', 'f', 'f', ' ', 'f', 'f'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

It should contain the bytes themselves:

```
>>> aa = np.array([chr(int(h, 16)) for h in data.split()])
>>> aa
array(['\x8a', '\xfd', '\xff', '\xff'],
      dtype='|S1')
>>> struct.unpack("<l", aa)
(-630,)
```